# Iterating over two Source and filter using a property in Scala

Tags: scala, streaming, akka-stream

I am trying to filter out common elements in terms of latest versions of the object and return another Source. My object looks like:

```
case class Record(id: String, version: Long)
```

My method's input are two Source:

```
val sourceA: Source[Record, _] = <>
val sourceB: Source[Record, _] = <>
```

`sourceA` and `sourceB` has common `id` of the `Record` object but there is a possibility that `version`s are different in both. I want to create a method which returns a `Source[Record, _]` which will have latest version for an id. I tried

```
val latestCombinedSource: Source[Record, _] = sourceA map {each => {
               sourceB.map(eachB => eachB.version > each.version? eachB: each)
               .....
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention what type of `Source` / what streaming library you are asking about (please update your question to clarify that). From the signatures in the code, I assume that this is about akka-stream. If that is correct, then you probably want to use [zipLatestWith](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#zipLatestWith%5BOut2,Out3%5D(that:akka.stream.Graph%5Bakka.stream.SourceShape%5BOut2%5D,_%5D,eagerComplete:Boolean)(combine:(Out,Out2)=%3EOut3):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BOut3%5D):

```
val latestCombinedSource: Source[Record, _] =
  sourceA.zipLatestWith(sourceB) { (a, b) =>
    if (a.version > b.version) a else b
  }
```

Note that there is also [zipWith](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#zipWith%5BOut2,Out3%5D(that:akka.stream.Graph%5Bakka.stream.SourceShape%5BOut2%5D,_%5D)(combine:(Out,Out2)=%3EOut3):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BOut3%5D) and I'm not 100% sure which one you'd want to use. The difference (quoted from the API docs) is: `zipWithLatest` "Emits when all of the inputs have at least an element available, and then each time an element becomes available on either of the inputs" while `zipWith` "Emits when all of the inputs have an element available".

Comment: Thanks MartinHH, yes, its Akka Source and looks like zipWithLatest is compiling. I will unit test and confirm